# Semantic Versioning Guidance With Packages Name Changes From a Git Repo

Tags: git, versioning

Our team is planning to rename a group of React components. Each component's version number has been, up until now, incremented based on semver guidance.

[semver.org](https://semver.org/#spec-item-8) does not clearly define what to do in this case - what version to increment during a renaming of a project. The changes are not breaking in the functional sense, so this could be technically described as backwards compatible, but users will need to reference a new package name in their package.json file in order to access new functionality.

What is best practice in this case - start at a new version number, increment to the next major number, or something else we haven't considered?

Comment: I’d say that “users will need” means that if they don’t change something it will break. Meaning the change is a breaking change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> users will need to reference a new package name in their package.json

This is similar to [`semver/semver` issue 148](https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/148), which discussed changes in dependencies.

> Upgrading the logger dependency would be an outgoing interface change and must be considered part of the public API.

In your case, this is not about dependencies, but is still a change to an "outgoing interface".
A change to the major version seems the recommended option.

Comment: This is what we were leaning towards. Thank you for the insight.